# How do I reinstate constraints collected with copy_term/3 in SICStus Prolog?

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd

The documentation says that

> `copy_term(+Term, -Copy, -Body)` makes a copy of `Term` in which all
>   variables have been replaced by new variables that occur nowhere
>   outside the newly created term. If `Term` contains attributed
>   variables, `Body` is unified with a term such that executing `Body`
>   will reinstate equivalent attributes on the variables in `Copy`.

I'm previously affirming numerical CLP(R) constraints over some variables, and at some point I collect these constraints using copy_term/3. Later, when I try to reinstate the constraints using 'call(Body)', I get an "Instantiation error" in arguments of the form `[nfr:resubmit_eq(...)]`

Here's a simplified example that demonstrates the problem:

```
:-use_module(library(clpr)).
{Old>=0, A>=0,A=<10, NR= Old+Z, Z=Old*(A/D)}, copy_term(Old,New,CTR), call(CTR).
```

Results in:

```
Instantiation error in argument 1 of '.'/2
! goal:  [nfr:resubmit_eq([v(-1.0,[_90^ -1,_95^1,_100^1]),v(1.0,[_113^1])])]
```

My question is: how do I reinstate the constraints in `Body` over `New`? I haven't been able to find concrete examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a bug in CLPR, which is unsupported.  We lost touch with the CLPR supplier a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

`copy_term/3` is a relatively new built-in predicate, that has been first introduced in SICStus about 2006. Its motivation was to replace the semantically cumbersome `call_residue/2` which originated from SICStus 0.6 of 1987 by a cleaner and more efficient interface that splits the functionality in two:

`call_residue_vars(Goal, Vars)` which is like `call(Goal)` and upon success unifies `Vars` with a list variables (in unspecified order) that are attached to constraints and have been created or affected in `Goal`.

`copy_term(Term, Copy, Body)` like `copy_term/2` and upon success unifies `Body` with a term to reinstate the actual constraints involved. Originally, `Body` was a goal that could be executed directly. Many systems that adopted this interface (like SWI, YAP) however, switched to use a list of goals instead. This simplifies frequent operations since you have less defaultyness, but at the expense of making reinstating more complex. You need to use `maplist(call,Goals)`.

Most of the time, these two built-in predicates will be used together. You are using only one which makes me a bit suspicious. You first need to figure out which variables are involved, and only then you can copy them. Typically you will use `call_residue_vars/2` for that. If you are copying only a couple of variables (as in your exemple) you are effectively **projecting** the constraints on these variables. This may or may not be your intention.

Comment: @j4nbur53: I'd say: Harmless. What is important is that `[]` is given if there is nothing left.

Comment: Yes. if you look at the implementation of call_residue/2 (still in YAP), you will see lots of copying going on anyway. But at least this "new" interface (10yrs old) is less costly and maintains certain consistencies - compared to the older interface.

Comment: The interface here is the result of ~20 years experience with constraints in SICStus.

Comment: Prior to this, `library(clpfd)` had tons of problems. Similarly, with delayed goals.

Comment: It is up to you to implement `copy_term(X,X,C)` more efficiently. By the same token, also  `copy_term(G+V,G+L)` might be implemented in a more efficient manner. It is all up to you.

Comment: Correction: The current YAP version already has an implementation that is very similar to this interface.